# Why were the Sunni Imams of fiqh made imams and nobody else?

Tags: sunni, history, islamic-scholar

How come the Sunni Imams of fiqh were made imam and nobody else? And similarly who decided credibility of muhadetheen.

Answer (score 1):

It is a process of peer review that is much similar to today's process of selecting the Noble Prize laureates. The Ummah as a whole has contributed to the review process as well.